# How to display recyclerview data inside a PopupWindow

Tags: android

I have to display a recyclerview inside a PopupWindow after a Volley call. I'm able to get the data after volley call and display it in the activity or a spinner but I not sure how to do that in a PopupWindow. Since I dont get where to initialize the recycleview and the adapter. Kindly tell me where shall I call the `GET_MALL_WEB_CALL()` mathod and how to pass the data into the popup window, so that I can access the data on the popup window. Could any one help in achieving this.Should I do this in some other way? I'm kinda stuck here.

**SetupActivity.java**

```
public class SetupActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private RequestQueue requestQueue2;
private RecyclerView mallRecyclerView;
private MallAdapter mallRecyclerAdapter;
List<ModelMall> newMallModels = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_setup);
    initViews();


    EditText popupButton = findViewById(R.id.editTextMall);
    popupButton.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
    popupButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        showPopup(v)
        }
    });
}


private void initViews() {
    imageVProfileSmall = findViewById(R.id.profileImg);

    //This is how I used to Initialize the recyclerview and adapter if I display the data in the same activity
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    mallRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    mallRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    mallRecyclerAdapter = new MallAdapter(this);
    mallRecyclerView.setAdapter(mallRecyclerAdapter);
}

private void GET_MALL_WEB_CALL() {

    String HTTP_SERVER_URL = "http://GETMALLAPI";
    JsonArrayRequest jsArrRequest = new JsonArrayRequest
            (Request.Method.GET, HTTP_SERVER_URL, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    GET_MALL_PARSE(response);
                    if (response.length() > 1) {
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Log.i("ERROR", "Event Web call Error");
                    }
                    mallRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    clear();
                    mallRecyclerAdapter.updateModels(newMallModels);
                    mallRecyclerView.setAdapter(mallRecyclerAdapter);
                }
            }) {

        //This is for Headers If You Needed
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            params.put("Authorization", "Bearer " + getFromSP("token"));
            return params;
        }

    };

        requestQueue2.add(jsArrRequest);
    
}

public void clear() {
    int size = newMallModels.size();
    newMallModels.clear();
    Log.i("LOL", String.valueOf(size));
}


public void GET_MALL_PARSE(JSONArray array) {
    clear();
    //List<EventsDataModel> newModels = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
        ModelMall GetMallDataModel = new ModelMall();
        Log.i("SUCCESS", "Event web call success");
        JSONObject json = null;
        try {
            json = array.getJSONObject(i);

            GetMallDataModel.setMallId(json.getString("$id"));//
            GetMallDataModel.setMallName(json.getString("Resourcetype_en"));//


            newMallModels.add(GetMallDataModel);
        } catch (JSONException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    if (array.length() != 0) {
        mallRecyclerAdapter.updateModels(newMallModels);
    }
}


public void showPopup(View view){

    //Create a View object yourself through inflater
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) view.getContext().getSystemService(view.getContext().LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View popupView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_mall_recycler, null);

    //Specify the length and width through constants
    int width = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    int height = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;

    //Make Inactive Items Outside Of PopupWindow
    boolean focusable = true;

    //Create a window with our parameters
    final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, width, height, focusable);

    //Set the location of the window on the screen
    popupWindow.showAtLocation(view, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

    //How to get the values from GET_MALL_PARSE() in the popup window ????
    

    // RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) popupView.findViewById(R.id.re);
    // ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<>();
    // data.add("my data");
    // data.add("my test data");
    // PopupRecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new PopupRecyclerViewAdapter(mContext,data);
    // recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    //Handler for clicking on the inactive zone of the window

    popupView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            //Close the window when clicked
            popupWindow.dismiss();
            return true;
        }
    });
}





private void saveInSp(String key, String value) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("PROJECT_NAME", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putString(key, value);
    editor.apply();
}

private String getFromSP(String key) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = this.getSharedPreferences("PROJECT_NAME", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return preferences.getString(key, "");
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}

}
```

**MallAdapter.java**

```
public class MallAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MallAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private Context context;
private final List<ModelMall> mallDataModels;
private static ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

public MallAdapter(Context context) {

    super();
    this.context = context;
    this.mallDataModels = new ArrayList<ModelMall>();

}

public void updateModels(List<ModelMall> newModels) {
    mallDataModels.clear();
    mallDataModels.addAll(newModels);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_item_layout, parent, false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
    final ModelMall dataAdapter = mallDataModels.get(position);
    viewHolder.tVMallName.setText(dataAdapter.getMallName());
    saveInSp("SelectedMallName", String.valueOf(dataAdapter.getMallId()));
    }





private static void removeSimpleProgressDialog() {
    try {
        if (mProgressDialog != null) {
            if (mProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                mProgressDialog = null;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ie) {
        ie.printStackTrace();

    }

}

public static void showSimpleProgressDialog(Context context, String title,
                                            String msg, boolean isCancelable) {
    try {
        if (mProgressDialog == null) {
            mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, title, msg);
            mProgressDialog.setCancelable(isCancelable);
        }

        if (!mProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
            mProgressDialog.show();
        }

    } catch (Exception ie) {
        ie.printStackTrace();
    }
}



@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    return mallDataModels.size();
}

private void saveInSp(String key, String value) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("PROJECT_NAME", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putString(key, value);
    editor.apply();
}


class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private TextView tVMallName;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        tVMallName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textMallName);
    }
}
```

}

**popup_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:gravity="center">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardCornerRadius="5dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/recyclerLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/recycle_box"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/value40_50_60"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text1"
                style="@style/selectOne"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                android:background="@drawable/recycle_select_box"
                android:fontFamily="@font/four_c_seven"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Select Mall"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="@dimen/value12_16_20"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                style="@style/selectOne"
                android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
                android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                tools:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                tools:listitem="@layout/recycler_item_layout"
                tools:itemCount="20"
                android:visibility="visible"
                >

            </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
            
        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove following from onCreate()

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
mallRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
mallRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
mallRecyclerAdapter = new MallAdapter(this);
mallRecyclerView.setAdapter(mallRecyclerAdapter);
```

You have to rewite the showPopup()

```
    public void showPopup(View view){



    //Create a View object yourself through inflater
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) view.getContext().getSystemService(view.getContext().LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View popupView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_mall_recycler, null);

    //Specify the length and width through constants
    int width = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    int height = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;

    //Make Inactive Items Outside Of PopupWindow
    boolean focusable = true;

    //Create a window with our parameters
    final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, width, height, focusable);

    //Set the location of the window on the screen
    popupWindow.showAtLocation(view, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

    //Initialize the elements of our window, install the handler

    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    mallRecyclerView = popupView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    mallRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    mallRecyclerAdapter = new MallAdapter(this);
    mallRecyclerView.setAdapter(mallRecyclerAdapter);

    GET_MALL_WEB_CALL();

    //Handler for clicking on the inactive zone of the window

    popupView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            //Close the window when clicked
            popupWindow.dismiss();
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```